# FB.api created Elements using jquery-on function

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, jquery-mobile, jquery-on

I´m creating list-elements with my facebook response data.

How do i have to use jquery´s .on (deprecated .live) function to get them styled from jquery.mobile?

jquery mobile is included in the head

facebook is included after the opening body

```
if (response.status === 'connected') {
FB.api("me/friends",{
          fields:'username,name,id',
          limit:10
        },function(res){

            $.each(res['data'],function(id,val){
                $('ul#list').append(
                    'some li´s'+'some content'
                );

            })
        })
}
```

Comment: after each loop use $('ul#list').listview('refresh');

Comment: If you want to find out more read this article: http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/

Comment: This will help me a lot in the next days. Thank you Gajotres